# SSH Connection Timeout

Tags: ssh, go

I am trying to make SSH connections using `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh` and I am kinda surprised that I can't seem to find out how to timeout the `NewSession` function (I actually don't seen any way to timeout anything). When I try to connect to a server that is having issues, this just hangs for a very long time. I have written something to use `select` with a `time.After` but it just feels like a hack. Something I haven't tried yet is to keep the underlying `net.Conn` in my struct and just keep doing `Conn.SetDeadline()` calls. Haven't tried this yet because I don't know if the crypto/ssh library overrides this or anything like that.

Anyone have a good way to timeout dead servers with this library? Or does anyone know of a better library?

Comment: Yeah, I think doing `NewClient()` with a `Conn` you `SetDeadline()` on is The Way(tm). Commenting not answering 'cause I don't have special familiarity with the `ssh` package. The output of `grep -R Deadline src/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh` makes me think the package won't get in your way but won't do it for you; the only mentions appear related to ssh port forwarding.

Comment: Yea the `SetDeadline()` works, but I gotta say something like a timeout missing from a library meant for making connections seems like a major oversight.. Not to sound ungrateful or anything and maybe if I have the time I will see if I can help include it

Comment: The thing that is a little stranger to me is that when I am setting up a connection to one of my servers that I know has died/is having issues (I can't ssh into it from the terminal) I don't get an error from `ssh.NewClientConn` at all nor does it return a nil Client. That is the main cause of my problem anyways, it is trying to call `NewSession` with a dead server that is passing as alive.

Comment: If `ssh.NewClientConn` returns ok, then the server isn't really dead since it can complete the ssh handshake.

Comment: @user3591723 -- I think the philosophy is if you can use another standard package for a piece of functionality, the stdlib authors often won't provide another way to do it, even if more convenient. For instance, people often use Go's `net/http` to write services returning JSON, and you can imagine convenience methods to make it easier to build those, but `net/http` (on its own) doesn't provide them; `net/http` has to be hooked up to `encoding/json` with other code.

Comment: @JimB I haven't looked much at the package source but I can safely say that something making it passed the `ssh.NewClientConn` can't necessarily succeed in starting a new session, which seems like strange behavior to me. When I get this `ssh: unexpected packet in response to channel open: <nil>` from trying `StartSession` if I go back to look at the error/output of `ssh.NewClientConn` I had definitely gotten a `nil` error there. If that is as expected I don't think it makes much sense.

Comment: @twotwotwo This feels a little different though. You can do all of that stuff in `net/http` with json without having to essentially go into the source and rewrite the same function they wrote but with a few lines added. There doesn't seem to be a way to solve this issue here without rewriting `Dial`, and while that isn't a difficult thing to do it is a little strange to me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One way to handle this transparently with the ssh package, is to create a connection with an idle timeout via a custom `net.Conn` which sets deadlines for you. However, this will cause the background Reads on a connection to timeout, so we need to use ssh keepalives to keep the connection open. Depending on your use case, simply using ssh keepalives as an alert for a dead connection may suffice.

```
// Conn wraps a net.Conn, and sets a deadline for every read
// and write operation.
type Conn struct {
    net.Conn
    ReadTimeout  time.Duration
    WriteTimeout time.Duration
}

func (c *Conn) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    err := c.Conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(c.ReadTimeout))
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return c.Conn.Read(b)
}

func (c *Conn) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    err := c.Conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(c.WriteTimeout))
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return c.Conn.Write(b)
}
```

You can then use `net.DialTimeout` or a `net.Dialer` to get the connection, wrap it in your `Conn` with timeouts, and pass it into `ssh.NewClientConn`.

```
func SSHDialTimeout(network, addr string, config *ssh.ClientConfig, timeout time.Duration) (*ssh.Client, error) {
    conn, err := net.DialTimeout(network, addr, timeout)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    timeoutConn := &Conn{conn, timeout, timeout}
    c, chans, reqs, err := ssh.NewClientConn(timeoutConn, addr, config)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    client := ssh.NewClient(c, chans, reqs)

    // this sends keepalive packets every 2 seconds
    // there's no useful response from these, so we can just abort if there's an error
    go func() {
        t := time.NewTicker(2 * time.Second)
        defer t.Stop()
        for range t.C {
            _, _, err := client.Conn.SendRequest("keepalive@golang.org", true, nil)
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
        }
    }()
    return client, nil
}
```

Comment: That definitely makes it more obvious what you're doing than what I came up with. Will probably implement something like this.

Answer (score 9):

Set the timeout on the [`ssh.ClientConfig`](http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#ClientConfig.Timeout).

```
cfg := ssh.ClientConfig{
    User: "root",
    Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
        ssh.PublicKeys(signer),
    },
    HostKeyCallback: ssh.FixedHostKey(hostKey),
    Timeout:         15 * time.Second, // max time to establish connection
}

ssh.Dial("tcp", ip+":22", &cfg)
```

When you call [`ssh.Dial`](http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Dial), the timeout will be passed to [`net.DialTimeout`](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/ssh/client.go#L172).

Comment: I prefer this answer much more