# Golang ssh client timeout not working as expected

Tags: go, ssh, timeout, sftp

I am writing a Golang ssh/sftp client which connects to a sftp server with a slowness in connecting and writing files, using `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh` package. I need to set `Connection timeout` and `SO timeout` (as we do in Java JSCH library).

First to achieve `Connection timeout` I was using `ssh.ClientConfig.Timeout`, but only worked for nanosecond and microsecond values, not for milliseconds and above, where I needed to set 5 seconds. According to the API doc also I assume `ssh.ClientConfig.Timeout` is used only for TCP socket connection creation and ssh handshake is not included there.

So then I tried `net.Conn.SetDeadline()` and it was for end-to-end `connection creation + writing file + connection closing`. Since this is also not fine, tried `net.Conn.SetWriteDeadline()` which looks like SO timeout (applied in TCP packet level) but timeout error is not appeared just after the duration elasped, instead comes out after the server's late reply or subsequent write operation starts.

So can someone please show the correct way of setting `Connection timeout` and `SO timeout` in Golang ssh package or tell whether this is supported or not?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554196/ssh-connection-timeout/31566330 answer your question?

Comment: I could be able to write a custom timeout code only for connection establishment, following Golang standard timeout pattern using goroutines+channels+select. But later we concluded that `net.Conn.SetDeadline()` which covers both connection establishment and file operations altogether is acceptable for our work.

Comment: For connection pooling scenarios you can set a defined future time point, i.e. `net.conn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(timeout_duration))` when creating the connection and retrieve the connection back from the pool. Then when you release the connection to pool after successful file operations, you can reset the deadline to infinity (keep it alive until next retrieval from the pool), i.e. `net.conn.SetDeadline(time.Time{})`